# Y axis inverted in code that should form a rectangle

Tags: java, rectangles

So i code consist of 3 parts 2 classes and test Idea is that 2 classes form a rectangle using inputs form the test.
This is code for test

```
@Test
    public void testRectangle1() {
        Point center = new Point(20, 30);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(center, 20, 20);
        assertAll(
                () -> assertEquals(10, rect.getTopLeft().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(30, rect.getBottomRight().getX()),
                () -> assertEquals(40, rect.getBottomRight().getY()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getWidth()),
                () -> assertEquals(20, rect.getHeight())
        );
    }
```

First class called Point it works fine.

```
public class Point {

    private int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point() {
        this(0, 0);
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void moveTo(int newX, int newY) {
        x = newX;
        y = newY;
    }

    public void moveRel(int dx, int dy) {
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (x != other.x)
            return false;
        if (y != other.y)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

So this is teh second class that forms recatangle itself. It consist of constructor on a few aditional methods for forming my rectangle

```
public class Rectangle {
    public int width = 0;
    public int height = 0;
    public Point center;

    public Rectangle(Point center, int width, int height) {
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
        this.center=center;
    }

    public Point getTopLeft() {
        Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
        point.moveRel(- width / 2, height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public Point getBottomRight() {
        Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
        point.moveRel(width / 2, - height / 2);
        return point;
    }

    public int getWidth() {

        return width;
    }


    public int getHeight() {

        return height;
    }
}
```

So the problem is it seems that y axis is somehow inverted becouse when i run the test it returns wrong value,
 `() -> assertEquals(20, rect.getTopLeft().getY())`, Where it returns 40 instead of 20 and test
`() -> assertEquals(40, rect.getBottomRight().getY())`, returns 2o instead of 40. So it seems that top left and bottom right point is inverted on y axis.

Comment: For me that is absolutly normal : https://imgur.com/a/KAijZgs That are correct for classic geometry, don't missunderstand with for example position on a screen of a device, whe the Y axis is inverted (numbers goes bigger while you go down)

Comment: Your output seems correct. I have one suggestion in code `this.center=center;` for this case the centre is pointing to the Point object you created. And in future, if the change that point than the centre will also change, but we expect the centre to not change if point is changed. To solve this in the constructor, you can create a new point object for the centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add height/2 in moveRel to get topLeft. Hence it is normal that you get 40 and not 20.

Seems there is a sign error before height parameters in:

```
public Point getTopLeft() {
    Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
    point.moveRel(- width / 2, height / 2);
    return point;
}

public Point getBottomRight() {
    Point point = new Point(center.getX(), center.getY());
    point.moveRel(width / 2, - height / 2);
    return point;
}
```